# Uniform Convergence of $nx^{2}(1-x)^{n}$ on $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, uniform-convergence

Uniform Convergence of $nx^{2}(1-x)^{n}$ on $[0,1]$

My attempt:

criterion: suppose $f_n:I\to\ J$ is a sequence of functions which converges point wise to a function $f$, then the convergence is uniform if and only if
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{x\in I}|f_n(x)-f(x)|=0$$.

I found out the point at which this function attains maximum. This happens at $x=2/(2+n)$. and the value of $f_{n}(x)$ at this point is $4/[2/n+1]$. So, with pointwise limit $f=0$, we have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{x\in I}|f_n(x)-f(x)|=0$$.

So, $f_{n}$ converges uniformly.

Is there a flaw in the proof?
Please clarify. Also suggest any alternative proof which is more analytic rather than calculation based, I mean if bounds can be established so that I don't have to find the maxima in the interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You found correctly the point at which
$$
x \longmapsto f_n(x):=nx^{2}(1-x)^{n}
$$
attains its maximum, that is $\displaystyle x=\frac{2}{n+2}$, but there is a mistake in your computation for the value of $f_n$ at this point, the right value is rather
$$
\frac{4 n \left(1-\frac{2}{2+n}\right)^n}{(2+n)^2}\sim \frac{4}{e^2}\frac{1}{n}, \quad \text{as} \quad n \to +\infty,
$$ and your function converges uniformly to $0$ on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.